# How to remove UIButton in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to create and remove uibutton. (iOS7)

My viewDidLoad function creates uibutton in the following way:

```
for (char a = 'A'; a <= 'Z'; a++)
{
    position = position+10;
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(getByCharacter:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", a] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(position, self.view.frame.size.height-40, 10.0, 10.0);
    button.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

}
```

Now I want to remove specific uibutton based on button text.

```
- (IBAction)getByCharacter:(id)sender{
 }
```

I don't know how to do this. Can anyone provide some sample code?

Comment: Isn't `[sender removeFromSuperview]` good enough?

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the button by calling

```
[sender removeFromSuperview];
```

in your callback (getByCharacter:). When you attach the selector to the button, the `sender` parameter will be the button which triggered the event. That means that you have an instance of it. With this instance you can now calll the `removeFromSuperview` method.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the button's title text and then remove it from superView if it matches to the specific character,

```
- (IBAction)getByCharacter:(id)sender{

  UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *) sender;
  if([myButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"C"]{
    [myButton removeFromSuperView];
  }
}
```